# Azure how to link Subscription in portal.azure with different subscription in dev.azure

Tags: azure-devops

Azure how to link Subscription in portal with different subscription in dev

i had created my appservice in azure from 'A' subscription but my azure pipeline in 'B' subscription. how to link or work with both at a time.

Answer (score 0):

if you use docker and a container registry you can push it there and let the appservice pull its image from it, then you could restart the appservice with the azure CLI, but it always depends on the project type unfortunately